# Android. How to clone newest version of Google Calendar?

Tags: android, git, calendar, open-source

I am trying to clone the newest possible Google Calendar source code from Android source code repo - [this one](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Calendar/).

I cloned the master branch (the main cloning link) and spent like a week to fix all the error since it was earlier built by eclipse I saw that's it super old version of google calendar. I checked all the branches and no matter if I take Android 5.0 or 7.0 it give me the same source code. Can someone explain me how to get the newer version, or how in general this repo works? **Thanks in advance, any help welcome!**

Comment: You mean to clone the current Android version's Calendar?

Comment: @Deandre yes, sir, could someone help me out????